# No such module Parse

Tags: swift, xcode

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class RegisterPageViewController: UIViewController {

   let myUser: PFUser = PFUser();

        myUser.username = userEmail
        myUser.password = userPassword
        myUser.email = userEmail


        myUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success:Bool!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            println("User successfully registered")
```

How do I fix a "no such Module" issue on Parse?

Comment: what should i put to fix the code

Comment: no Xcode on mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have been able to solve this Issue in the GitHub Chat. You have forgotten to install [Parse Framework.](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX)

You need to either install it with `pod 'Parse'` or drag and drop the Framework into your project and use the Bridging Header.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have a Swift only app, Parse's SKD is in Objective C so you are going to have to make your app a swift/Objective C app, and add Parse to your bridging header

[Here's a good post on how to add a bridging header](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/)